# Convert special characters to HTML entities, Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, output

I am trying to convert special characters for safe output in my view using Laravel.  I know blade does this for you - but all my data is being displayed via JavaScript Ajax requests.  My original function for accomplishing this doesn't seem to work (used with CodeIgniter):

```
       //sanitize tasks for safe output
        function sanitize_object_h( $array ) {
            $array_modified = $array;

            foreach( $array_modified as $object ) {
                foreach( $object as &$item ) {
                    $item = htmlentities( $item, ENT_QUOTES );
                }
                //end foreach
            }
            //end foreach
            return $array_modified;

        }
        //end sanitize_object_h
```

Does Laravel provide a convenient way of converting large numbers of database records for safe output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have not provided an `XSS` filter, as it is more at the users discretion. There is, however, a great article with a ready-to-go XSS filter function located [at this link](http://usman.it/xss-filter-laravel/).

I hope this helps!